# "Array" Function is Preventing Program From Running Properly

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

My function isn't working properly. The program runs but when it gets to the for loop the function doesn't work and stops the program even though it is supposed to continue looping. If you could please check my Array function and tell me if there is anything i'm not understanding or doing correctly.

Thanks for your time.

I know for a fact the loop isn't the problem because when I remove the function it works fine. I've also tried placing the 'b' within the function array parameter like this "int Array(int a[b], int b,  int c);"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*Function*/

int Array(int a[], int b,  int c);

/*Main Program*/
int main()

{

int S, C, *A, *B;
printf("How Many Numbers Would You Like in Array A and B? ");
scanf("%d\n", & S);

/*For Loop Asking The User to Enter a Value and using the Array function to calculate/store the B[] Value*/
for (C=0; C<=S; ++C){
    printf("\nWhat is A[%d]  ", C);
    scanf("%d", & A[C]);
    B[C] = Array(A, S, C);
    }
}


/*Function*/    
int Array(int a[], int b, int c)
{
if (a[c] < 0){
        return a[c] * 10;

    } else {
        return a[c] * 2;

                }
}
```

Expected Results:

- The program asks the user to input the array size which will be used for *A and *B
- The program uses a for loop to ask the user to enter a value for each position in array *A, using that value to compute the value for each matching B position

Actual Results:

- The program asks the user to input the array size which will be used for *A and *B
- The program uses a for loop to ask the user to enter a value for each position in array *A, the program asks the user for one value then stops running.

Comment: You should add `fflush(stdout);` after printing your prompt, before the `scanf`, to force the prompt to be displayed (since it doesn't end with a newline).

Comment: Man you need better variable names... What do `A` and `B` point to? You never initialize them before you start using them.

Answer (score 1):

You're not allocating any memory for the array A. You just declare it as a pointer to int, then start writing values to it, which are going to some random memory location. After the first scanf that gets S, you need to assign `A = malloc(S * sizeof(int))` before accessing it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did add that line and it still isn't working properly. I do understand what your saying though, is there another way to initialize it?

Comment: There are probably other errors; that was just the most obvious. A good debugger would certainly help.

Comment: @Beginner - You also need to allocate memory for `B` like this `B = malloc(S * sizeof(int))`

Comment: Thanks for the response both of you. @RishikeshRaje I actually did do that and it didn't work still. I ended up initializing the size of the array and it worked so maybe my compiler doesn't support malloc? Example: A[99999], B[99999]. and it worked so im guessing its the compiler but im a beginner so I'm probably talking nonsence

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your compiler. It will be at least 2 years before you're even allowed to think that. More likely you're doing something like allocating 10 elements and accessing the 11th.